# Protective measure against powering inductive loads

Tags: mosfet, diodes, inductive

From various chip manufacturer articles and other post in this site, I still have doubts on my circuit for switching inductive loads.

I have two setup here that both switches an inductive but using diferent MOSFET one is a P-Channel and the Other is N-Channel. A zener diode is placed on the Gate and source of both, the value for this zener is calculated to be greater than your typical Vgate voltage and less than the Fets Maximum Vgs rating.

The best suppression for inductive seems to be a Schottky and zenner parrallel to the inductive load. Schottkey should atleast handle the full current of the inductor (1A to 2A which is pretty common). For the Zener selection is seems to be  geater than supply voltage yet less than the fets Vds(max).

[image]

As for my questions:

- When the coil collapses, are there danger of the current going back through the mosfets?
- For the NMOS setup in blue line is there danger of it going back to the power rails? I do not want to stress my PMICs
- For the PMOS is that ground safe to be connected directly to the logic grounds? I would like the setup to be able to have an alternate function where it can power digital ICs where having the same ground is important

Comment: D1 is the wrong way round. The MOSFET will never turn on properly. Was this intentional? Correspondingly R3 would likely need to be a few kohm too.

Comment: Is a gate drive driving these MOSFETs or is something else like an I/O pin? If it’s an I/O And a logic level mosfet then I agree with Andy aka to use higher gate resistance.

Comment: *For the Zener selection is seems to be geater than supply voltage yet less than the fets Vds(max).* - NO - the zener voltage plus the maximum supply voltage should be less than Vds(max) - I wouldn't go closer than two-thirds either.

Comment: The diode doesn't need to be anything special either and certainly doesn't need to be a schottky especially as they have high leakage current and this application doesn't require high speed at all unless you are using fast PWM. (I assumed a relay coil BTW).

Comment: Also the whole point of D3 and D4 or D5 and D6 is to divert that voltage and current produced by collapsing magnetic field of inductive load away from MOSFET.

Comment: @Andyaka The PMOS driving circuit kinda look like [this](https://ibb.co/NTyKX8G), i just simplified in that schematic. Im not sure actually but i think D1 is correct??

Comment: That circuit is incorrect too. Where did it come from? It reminds me a little of the convoluted drawing style of an EE participant (fantasist) on this site.

Comment: Voltage supply connected to R6 shouldn’t be that high in that circuit. Something something like 10V or 12V is better. With R6 as 100 ohm and R5 as 1k.

Comment: @Andyaka actually i just came up with this one. Here what i was thinking when making that one. Assuming the Vgs of the PMOS to be fully on is -5v. i use a voltage divider controlled by a logic NMOS to switch the step down voltage so that Vgs is around 10v (where PMOS max Vgs is +- 20v). Am i missing on something important here?

Comment: Gate voltage cannot drop more than 0.7 volts below source voltage - as I said right at the top of this comment thread: D1 is the wrong way round. Think about it!!!

Comment: Ohhh... the gate voltage is basically being pulled up by the source voltage, Since the source voltage is always higher than the output of the voltage divider, Im sorry took me so long to get that, Yes the diode is the wrong way around

Comment: @Leoman12 I find it hard to make 10v or 12v when the input voltage is variable. The more i think about it the more i see the flaws in my circuit. the voltage divider at 7v input (lowest allowable input before PMIC locksout) would spit out 5.6, that not enough to turn on the FET

Comment: @jake quin, what voltage did you plan on using for your inductive load? It’s possible to obtain a lower voltage from that supply voltage.

Comment: @Leoman12 the plan is to drive 7-60v DC loads, and no, the input cant go lower than 7v. the PMOS fully on at -5v

Comment: @Andyaka Im just starting to realise how bad that design was. I just want to drive that PMOS with a 5v GPIO, and the way how PMOS works and my wide voltage range is not making it easy for me to come of a solution T^T

Answer (score 1):

> *When the coil collapses, are there danger of the current going back
>   through the mosfets?*

Yes there is. It's a certainty that current will flow into the parasitic capacitance of the MOSFET and, although less certain, if dv/dt is fast enough, it can raise the gate voltage sufficiently (via internal capacitive coupling) and reactivate the MOSFET temporarily. This happens quite commonly.

> *For the NMOS setup in blue line is there danger of it going back to
>   the power rails? I do not want to stress my PMICs*

Bearly anything at all will happen here. Because the MOSFET drain source capacitance is real (as previously mentioned) the flyback current passing through the zener is slightly egged into pushing a little current back into the supply due to that capacitance but, it is a minor, minor problem.

> *For the PMOS is that ground safe to be connected directly to the logic
>   grounds? I would like the setup to be able to have an alternate
>   function where it can power digital ICs where having the same ground
>   is important*

Similarly to directly above there can be a small injection of charge but, providing the ground plane is good, it won't be noticed. As with either (2) and (3) keep the zener/diode close to the inductors.

Comment: As to answer(1). and my guess to solve this problem is to add another diode at the gate blocking the current from reactivating the FET?

Comment: @Jakequin no that won't work - it happens internally and the best you can do is clamp the gate-source voltage (when not required to be activated) to some voltage close to 0 volts. However, it is an extreme example I'm quoting and only really happens on high voltage supplies with fast dv/dt.